# Unity Visual Studio annoying indent

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a Unity project with Visual Studio for code and I'm getting crazy with auto-indent, it's weird. Is there any way to change it?

PS: Sorry for my english.

Comment: Yes there are ways to change it. Have you tried or researched anything about it before asking?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18324386/1997232) might help (replace C++ with C#). Notice Resharper answer, perhaps Unity introduces some formatting too.

Comment: Yes of course, I've searched for a solution but didn't find it...

Comment: @Sinatr that's just what i wanted!!! i've solved, thanks a lot boss!

Answer (score 0):

Click on tools > options > text editor > basic > tabs then select none under the indenting then "ok"

Comment: That's not that i'm looking for, my problem is with brackets "{ }", when i press enter they jump to downline but this only happens when i'm working with Unity... you know what i mean?