# Stop ReSharper or Visual Studio from reformatting my code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper, reformatting

I am currently working on a Windows Form application, and setting the text of labels in the `InitializeComponent()` method of `MyForm.Designed.cs`. I'm setting it to a function call so it looks like the first line, but it keeps getting reformatted into the second line. The first line works perfectly, it's just that it's getting reformatted.

```
this.teamGroup.Text = LocalizedLanguage.GetValue("SelectedTeamLabel");
this.teamGroup.Text = "Selected Team";
```

Additionally, this is also happening for the TabIndex as well.

I have:

- C# 6.0
- Visual Studio 2015 Community
- ReSharper 10.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jacob, you shouldn't modify the code inside InitializeComponent manually.

```
/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeComponent()
```

If you want to add something for the components use the following approach:

```
public YourForm ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CustomInitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CustomInitializeComponent()
    {
        teamGroup.Text = LocalizedLanguage.GetValue("SelectedTeamLabel");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can switch off automatic code formatting in VS under Options in Tools menu, selecting the **Text Editor ->  -> Formatting -> General** page, and unchecking all the boxes there. You will still be able to manually format when all of the auto-formatting settings are turned off.

You can check the similar thing here [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298072/how-do-i-turn-off-auto-formatting-in-vs2013-for-c) or [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737222/turn-off-auto-formatting-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @Jacob, if that works for you can you accept the answer.

Comment: So I could do that but they I will lose all refactoring that VS provides. I like the refactoring in general- just not in these specific cases.

Comment: you can turn off the feature which you don't want in your project, other will work as it is.